# How to print seconds since epoch in log4j log

Tags: log4j

I have a conversion pattern in my log4j configuration. I know how to print it in %d{ISO8601}... but if I want it in seconds since epoch (1/1/1970), what's the format?

Answer (score 1):

According to the accepted answer to the question, [log4j: current time in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11757348/55597), log4j does not natively provide the capability to do this.