# Current milliseconds since the start of execution

Tags: java, log4j

How I get the current milliseconds since the start of execution in log4j patternlayout?

Eg:

```
000000.000| blah|
000000.000| blah|
000000.000| exception|
000000.001| foo|
```

Comment: From here, it looks like it's `r`: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html (But I haven't tried/verified)

Comment: Possible already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757348/log4j-current-time-in-milliseconds

Comment: %r don't return ms like the example.