# how to pass datetime as long value in log4j2.properties file in jdbc appender

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a entity with a Long parameter that record 'System.currentTimeMillis()' value.

In log4j2 properties file, I need to get current Time in millisecond and pass as a column value, like below:

```
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].type = Column
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].name = CREATION_TIME
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].literal = **???**
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].isUnicode = false
```

I can not use `isEventTimestamp` because my parameter is a long!

how can I do it.

Comment: would converting your long parameter to a Date be an option?

Comment: this system is runnig, we can not change type of a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it to solve my problem:

```
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].type = Column
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].name = CREATION_TIME
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].pattern = %d{UNIX_MILLIS}
appender.systemLog.columnConfigs[0].isUnicode = false
```

special thanks to  [thegeko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43472557/4723495)